# Why do we have to use Gravatar for Careers 2.0?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, gravatar

Stack Exchange has moved away from using Gravatar.com for your profile picture, so can we do the same with Careers 2.0?

It is a real pain to have to update your picture on Careers.

Gravatar don't even allow login using OpenID which would kind of diminish the issue

Comment: I'm confused about your last comment. We do allow OpenID logins.

Comment: Well... Gravatar doesn't, which was my point (ranting mode in full swing). I will update the post.

Comment: You can follow the advice in the linked question and link different email just for your careers profile.